# How to ignore dbms statements from Oracle script during ANTLR parsing

Tags: java, antlr3

I am developing a oracle script parser using ANTLR. I have done most of it but I am facing problems in parsing the dbms statements. I want to ignore these statements. Is there a way of ignoring these sort of statements during parsing?

Comment: Why not to use `DBMS_SQL.PARSE` from oracle? [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF)

Comment: Because it is a java based compiler.